# Call the constructor of the unknown children

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class

I want to call the constructor;

```
class anAbstractClass
{
 public: anAbstractClass(inputdatatype){/*blablabla*/}
};

class aChield : public anAbstactClass
{
/*
...
*/
}

void _engine::initShader(_anAbstractClass** inShader)
{
    *inShader = new /*???*/(inputdata for the construcor)
}

aChield* theChield;
_engine* myEngine = new _engine();
myEngine->initShader(&theChield);
```

So, how can I call the constructor at the /*???*/?
Thx ahead for the answers!

Comment: Are you trying to implement the factory method pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice idea, but there is no support to get the exact type of a pointer at runtime.

In your `initShader` method, `inShader` is of type `anAbstractClass**` and there is no way to get the information that it was a pointer to pointer to a derived class before the method call.

So you need the change your code, maybe you can use some Factory or something like this.

Comment: Okay, I am sad a bit :'(
But, the I have to look out at oodesign.com
THX for then 2 answers. This is a cool site! :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that.  How is `initShader` going to know which child constructor to call, when all it knows is the base class?

What I think you want here, is a templated function:

```
template <typename T>
void _engine::initShader(T ** inShader) 
{ 
    *inShader = new T(inputdata for the construcor) 
}
```

Comment: I was typing it as you posted it.

Comment: Im curious, how can I do that so, that the user can use the initShader only with the anAbstractClass (and her childrens)?

Comment: @User408...: after the new, call `inShader->SomeFunctionDefinedInanAbstractClass()`.  You'll get a compiler error if the object doesn't have that function.